# How to take a string with spaces from a file in C

Tags: c, string, file-io

```
main()
{
    FILE *fin;
    char line[50];
    char exp[SIZE];
    fin=fopen("prefix.txt","r");

    if(fin==NULL)
    {
         printf("\nFile Cannot be Opened\n");
    }
    else
    {
         printf("\nfile opened\n");

         while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fin)!=NULL)
         {
              sscanf(line, "%s", exp);
              delete_spaces(exp);
              convert(exp);
         }
    }
    fclose(fin);
    getch();
}
```

My file is containing string with spaces and when I am reading a line from it, the line is containing only first word and ignoring string after space.

Comment: Google it before asking a question

Comment: DON'T USE `while(!feof(fin))`
@Jayesh please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: sorry its not working

Comment: The `fclose()` should be in the `else` clause.  You've got the line (well, if the line is short enough — use a bigger size, like 4096) in `line`; it will have words with blanks separating them.  What else are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, because `sscanf()` (along with all the `scanf()` functions) uses the `%s` specifier to read a string **up to the first whitespace character.** So you explicitly truncate your line with that one call. It seems to me that you want to process the entire line, so that sscanf is just useless -- remove it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the EOF statement to read the file entirely , e.g in your case :

```
while ((line = getc(fin)) != EOF)
```